# Electron macOS: Change icon of files

Tags: javascript, node.js, reactjs, macos, electron

we're trying to find and use an electron API that let us change the icon of a file (macOS only).

Our app accept a folder from the macOS finder and we want a way/api to get the current folder icon and change it by passing a new `icns` or `png` file. Is it possible?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should use the [NSWorkspace.setIcon](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/appkit/nsworkspace/1529882-seticon) function but there is no way to use this API from electron.

Looks like electron doesn't support the direct access to this API and some related issues [exists](https://github.com/electron/electron/search?q=nsworkspace&type=issues).

As a workaround you can create (compile) a macos binary that only do this and then exec it from electron code using [child_process.execFile](https://nodejs.org/api/child_process.html).

Comment: Thank you Alessandro ! Any link or resource to compile that binary?

Comment: https://swift.org/getting-started/#using-the-package-manager to start with swift from cli. Or use xcode.